# Install MatPlotLib 1.2.x on OS X Lion 10.7.4 and Python 3.2.2

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib, osx-lion

I asked a question a couple of days ago regarding installing numpy on the same system. Thankfully, I managed to solve that one myself but unfortunately I am now stuck trying to install matplotlib.

I first of all tried the current distributed version but had no luck with that so I thought i would download the git repository and try that. I have got this far:

- changed the `make.osx` file so that it will work in Python 3:

  - `import urllib` -> `import urllib.request`
  - `urllib.urlretrieve()` -> `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`

Even after that I still had a problem with it not finding the freetype2 headers. I googled around and discovered that I could solve this by editing a line in `setupext.py`:

- `'darwin' : [],` -> `'darwin' : ['/usr/local'],`

However, I still get an error message when using the `make.osx` file. Here is how I am calling the file from Terminal:

- `sudo make -f make.osx PREFIX=/usr/local PYVERSION=3.2 fetch deps mpl_build mpl_install`

I realise that matplotlib isn't officially supported on Python 3 yet but I thought that maybe someone somewhere as at least managed to get it to compile/install?

Any help would be much appreciated,

Adam.

I have included the error I get below:

```
basedirlist is: ['/usr/local']
============================================================================
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: 1.2.x
                python: 3.2.2 (v3.2.2:137e45f15c0b, Sep  3 2011, 17:28:59)
                        [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
              platform: darwin

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                 numpy: 1.6.2rc1
             freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)

OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                libpng: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
               Tkinter: Tkinter: version not identified, Tk: 8.5, Tcl: 8.5
                  Gtk+: no
                        * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                        * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
       Mac OS X native: yes
                    Qt: no
                   Qt4: Qt: 4.7.4, PyQt4: 4.8.6
                PySide: no
                 Cairo: no

OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
              datetime: present, version unknown
              dateutil: matplotlib will provide
                  pytz: matplotlib will provide
adding pytz

OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: /bin/sh: gs: command not found
                 latex: no

[Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
============================================================================
pymods ['pylab']
packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor', 'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units', 'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay', 'pytz', 'dateutil', 'dateutil.zoneinfo']
running build
running build_py
copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.2/matplotlib/mpl-data
copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlib.conf -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.2/matplotlib/mpl-data

running build_ext
building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
gcc-4.2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -DPYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I./freetype2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.2/src/ft2font.o
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/bytearrayobject.h:9,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/Python.h:73,
                 from ./CXX/WrapPython.h:58,
                 from ./CXX/Extensions.hxx:37,
                 from src/ft2font.h:6,
                 from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:45,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:70,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:47,
                 from ./CXX/Python3/Exception.hxx:47,
                 from ./CXX/Python3/Objects.hxx:45,
                 from ./CXX/Python3/Extensions.hxx:52,
                 from ./CXX/Extensions.hxx:42,
                 from src/ft2font.h:6,
                 from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/bits/c++locale.h: In function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(int* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/bits/c++locale.h:77: error: ‘va_start’ was not declared in this scope
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/bits/c++locale.h:85: error: ‘va_end’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/bytearrayobject.h:9,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/Python.h:73,
                 from ./CXX/WrapPython.h:58,
                 from ./CXX/Extensions.hxx:37,
                 from src/ft2font.h:6,
                 from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:45,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:70,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:47,
                 from ./CXX/Python3/Exception.hxx:47,
                 from ./CXX/Python3/Objects.hxx:45,
                 from ./CXX/Python3/Extensions.hxx:52,
                 from ./CXX/Extensions.hxx:42,
                 from src/ft2font.h:6,
                 from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/x86_64/bits/c++locale.h: In function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(int* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/x86_64/bits/c++locale.h:77: error: ‘va_start’ was not declared in this scope
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/x86_64/bits/c++locale.h:85: error: ‘va_end’ was not declared in this scope
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccafJH1l.out
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [mpl_build] Error 1
```

Comment: Is your build environment incomplete? The error message about stdarg.h suggests that you are missing a header file. This is just a guess, but since you mention Lion, maybe you should set OSX_SDK_VER=10.7 on your make command line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the build target to 10.7 and it now works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay...I think have managed to get **matplotlib** to install now...

1. First of all you need to install **numpy**. I have instructions to do this on another post: [install numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557857/install-numpy-for-python-3-2-3-on-os-x-10-7-4)
2. Now open **Terminal** and clone the git repository for **matplotlib** (assumes you have git installed):

   - `git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git` (this might take a while)
3. Once the clone is complete open your user folder in **Finder**
4. In your user folder open the matplotlib directory
5. There is a file called `make.osx' open this with **TextEdit** (or similar)
6. Change the following lines:

   - `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6`
   - `OSX_SDK_VER=10.6`

   To:

   - `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7`
   - `OSX_SDK_VER=10.7`
7. Change the following lines:

   - `${PYTHON} -c 'import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve("${ZLIBURL}", "${ZLIBFILE}")' &&\
     ${PYTHON} -c 'import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve("${PNGURL}", "${PNGFILE}")' &&\
     ${PYTHON} -c 'import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve("${FREETYPEURL}", "${FREETYPEFILE}")'`

   To:

   - `${PYTHON} -c 'import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlretrieve("${ZLIBURL}", "${ZLIBFILE}")' &&\
     ${PYTHON} -c 'import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlretrieve("${PNGURL}", "${PNGFILE}")' &&\
     ${PYTHON} -c 'import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlretrieve("${FREETYPEURL}", "${FREETYPEFILE}")'`
8. Save the changes
9. Open the file called `setupext.py` in **idle**
10. Find the line `'darwin' : [],` and change it to `'darwin' : ['/usr/local'],`
11. Save the file
12. Open **Terminal** again and type the following:

    - `sudo make -f make.osx PREFIX=/usr/local PYVERSION=3.2 fetch deps mpl_build mpl_install`
13. After some time matplotlib should be installed in the following directory:

    - `/usr/local/lib/Python3.2/site-packages/`
14. Open the above directory and also the following directory:

    - `/Library/Python/3.2/site-packages/`
15. Copy/move the following directories from `/usr/local/lib/Python3.2/site-packages/` to `/Library/Python/3.2/site-packages/`:

    - `dateutil`
    - `matplotlib`
    - `mpl_toolkits`
16. **matplotlib** should be now installed
17. If you open **idle** and type `import matplotlib` it shouldn't return an error
18. I tried out the `matplotlib/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4_wtoolbar.py` file and it seems works fine

Hope someone else finds this useful!

Thanks again for the assistance,

Adam.

Comment: Well done on working all that out. Please head to the matplotlib mailing lists and help them work out how to make it easier! ;-)